# Bad video card or power supply?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

Greetings SU,

My PC just stopped functioning properly after it has been running fine for nearly 2 years.  When I turn it on, all of the case fans turn on, and I see the case LEDs light up.  My Graphics card doesn't look like it's driving the monitor - I can see the fan on it try to spin up, but it stops after running for about 5 seconds.  It then tries again, spins for 5 seconds, and then stops.  It's a PCI-E card, and it has a power connector going to it.

I don't hear/feel my hard drives spin up either, which makes me lean towards it being a power supply issue, but I'm thrown off by the fact that the fans and case lights are working fine.  Can this happen with power supplies?  I have [this OCZ GameXStream PS](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817341002).  I've seen on another answer that there are power supply testers, but I don't want to spend more than I have to.  I might end up getting one anyway since I do plan to build again sometime.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all - it was the PSU - scared me at first seeing as the machine didn't turn on when I hit the power button.. had a bad connection somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hop down to the local parts shop and pick up a PSU for $50, install it outside of your case and see if your problems are gone. If not, try using on-board video and removing your card, or replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the system doesn't show the BIOS and you feel that the hard disks aren't spinning then it sounds like power supply failure.

Power Supply Failure Symptoms 
More often then not, a power supply will just quit working instead of warning you that it is about to kick the bucket.

Here is a list of common power supply failure symptoms:

- There are strange noises coming from the back side of the computer where the power cord plugs into the power supply.
- Nothing happens when the computer power button is pressed. Sometimes a light may flash or flash continuously in the front of the computer or on the back of the power supply.
- The computer turns on for a few seconds and then turns off. (Sometimes this is unfortunately associated with motherboard failures.)
- Computer turns on for a while, but when games or other applications are using the computer steadily, it will turn off or I get a blue screen.

([reference](http://www.squidoo.com/power-supply-failure-symptoms))

If you were already planning on purchasing a power supply, give it a shot.  If it still doesn't work then trouble shoot the video card, however, if the system doesn't boot, there a possibility of Motherboard failure.

Answer (score 1):

At this point a power supply tester might be worth the money (about $35).  Power supplies produce multiple voltages and if the right one went bad (say the +5 volt), you might still get fans (+12 volt) but not much else.  I would think the case LEDs would be +5 so that's an argument that says PSU might be working and thus pointing at the graphics card being the culprit.

A good PSU tester will have plugs that match connectors on the motherboard, PATA hard disks/CDS, floppies, and both 4 and 8 pin motherboard/GPU plugs.  You're going to have to either know or research what the appropriate voltages (lit leds) should be for your system.

If you're a gamer (I read that to mean you buy expensive PSUs) then the tester might save some $$$ in the long run.

Comment: are the expensive power supplies worth it?  if it's the PSU, then I'm clearly going to have to say no..

Comment: If your components suck up a LOT of power then it's probably going to be expensive.  You don't want to be underpowered because that puts your entire system at risk.  Buy a PSU from a reputable company that consistently gets good reviews.  Getting something rated about 30 to 50% more than the current MAX draw on your system is probably a good idea.  Try not to buy features you don't need.  I see excellent 650 watt power supplies on sale for $65 all the time.  If you need much more than that be prepared to pay more.